# I am unsure about raising e to the natural log of an absolute value (simple differential equation example)

Tags: calculus, differential

I am unsure what happens to the absolute value when solving this equation.

The original question was asking: 
Find a particular solution to 
$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2y; y(1) = 3$

I have simplified it to the stage of $ln|y| = 2x+C$

What I am unsure about is what happens when I raise both sides to $e$.
 What happens to the absolute value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You get $\pm y=e^C\cdot e^{2x}$. The constant sign of $y(x)$ gets absorbed into the constant to form a new constant $C_1=\pm e^C$, to get the general solution $y(x)=C_1e^{2x}$.

---

**Added note:** If you still feel uncomfortable with the absolute value and sign, then take the homogenous solution as a hint and use the separation ansatz to get a strict derivation.

For example, with $y'=2y+f(x)$, insert $y(x)=e^{2x}u(x)$, which is perfectly permissible since $x\mapsto e^{2x}$ is a positive smooth function. This results after a short computation in $u'(x)=e^{-2x}f(x)$ or

$$u(x)=C+\int_{x_0}^x e^{-2s}f(s)\,ds$$

where now $C=u(x_0)$ is an arbitrary integration constant, positive, negative or zero, and then

$$y(x)=Ce^{2x}+\int_{x_0}^x e^{2(x-s)}f(s)\,ds=y(x_0)e^{2(x-x_0)}+\int_{x_0}^x e^{2(x-s)}f(s)\,ds$$

completely avoiding all discussion of $\ln|y|$.

Answer (score 1):

$|y|$ is **just a real number**, which means that to begin with, if $\ln |y| = 2x + C$, it certainly follows that $|y| = e^{2x + C}$.  There is no problem so far.

The confusing part comes after taking $\exp$ to both sides, if you want to eliminate the absolute value signs from $y$.  To do so, you need a bit of a more sophisticated argument.  Essentially you say $y = \pm e^{2x + C}$ for each $x$, and then by continuity it will need to be the same $+$ or $-$ for all $x$.

As LutzL says, we often set $A = \pm e^C$ so that the solution becomes $y = A e^{2x}$ for some $A \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Substitute $| y| = a > 0$ and then we have:

$$\ln | y | = \ln a = 2x + C$$
$$e^{\ln a} = e^{2x + C}$$
$$a = |y| = e^{2x + C}$$

Answer (score 0):

The condition $y(1)=3$ will decide the sign of $y$: only one sign is possible. You can take exponents to get $|y|=\exp(2x+C)$. Because $\exp$ is always positive, the condition $y(1)=3$ will determine the sign of $y$.

Another way of doing it is to write the constant as $\ln D$ rather than $C$ and say you'll let the condition $y(1)=3$ determine the sign of D. Then you have
$$\begin{align}
\ln y &= 2x + \ln D\\
y &= De^{2x}
\end{align}$$

Now plug in $y(1)=3$ to get your solution.

Comment: A while ago I asked a related question on this topic and Hagen von Eitzen made a [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573276/how-to-deal-with-negative-x-when-integrating-reciprocal-to-log#comment1213010_573276) I found very helpful.

Comment: Careful; your statement that "because exp is always positive, the condition will determine the sign of $y$" is not true.  From $|y| = \exp(2x + C)$, it follows that $y$ could be positive **or** negative; either way the absolute value makes the result consistent.  You need to conclude $y = \pm \exp(2x + C)$ and then use the initial condition $y(1) = 3$ to find whether to use $+$ or $-$.

Comment: @Goos thanks for your comment. I _think_ that's what I meant, although I might have been unclear. With an equation like this you're going to have, in general, $y<0$ or $y>0$ for all $x$ because for all $\exp(x)$ is always $>0$. Which way it goes depends on the condition, or do I have this wrong?

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood what you mean by "the condition".  I thought you meant the condition $|y| = \exp(2x + C)$.  Do you mean the initial condition $y(1) = 3$?  Regardless, I'm still a bit confused why you say "because $\exp$ is always positive, the condition will determine the sign of $y$".  I agree that $y(1) = 3$ determines the sign of $y$, but I don't see why that is a result of $\exp$ being positive.  Rather, $\exp$ being positive just means that your equation $|y| = \exp(2x + C)$ is consistent.

Comment: sorry, yes, I meant the condition $y(1)=3$. Regarding $\exp$ being positive, I was thinking if you had an equation $|y|=f(x)$, where $f(x)$ wasn't strictly positive or negative for all $x$ then you wouldn't get $y$ being strictly positive or negative after applying the initial/boundary condition. But I take your point.